# How to copy an entire subtree in emacs outline-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there any command or function that let you copy a subtree at cursor location in emacs outline-mode?

```
*blogs
**blog A
***an article title
blah blah blah
yada yada yada
***another article title...
**blog B
***an article...
```

I want to copy only

```
blah blah blah
yada yada yada
```

part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you collapse that sub-tree you can then copy it in one step, just by copying the visible heading.

That will include the heading in the copied text, mind, but that might not be a big deal?